# como llamo una funcion dentro de otra funcion kotlin

Tags: funciones, kotlin

tengo las 3 siguientes funciones que quisiera llamar en una sola función en kotlin: para escribir un solo numero y que me evalué las 3, dejo mis códigos. ósea crear una 4ta funcion que llame alas otras 3 por ejemplo  la funcion fun llamadaAtodasLasFunciones me sirva para llamar a las otras, como se le darian los parametros, gracias soy nuevo en esto de kotlin

```
fun llamadaAtodasLasFunciones(no se como llamarlas :( ) { 
}
 

fun meses2021(mesesCorrientes : Int) {
    when(mesesCorrientes){
    1 -> println("Enero")
    2 -> println("Febrero")
    3 -> println("Marzo")
    4 -> println("Abril")
    5-> println("Mayo")
    6 -> println("Junio")
    7 -> println("Julio")
    8-> println("Agosto")
    9-> println("Septiembre")
    10 -> println("Octubre")
    11 -> println("Noviembre")
    12 -> println("Diciembre")
    else -> { 
    println("No esta dentro de los meses del año")
    
}
}
}

fun apuntarMese(apuntar : Int) {
    when(apuntar) {
    1,2,3,4 -> println("corresponde al primer cuatrimestre")  
    5,6,7,8 -> println("corresponde al segundo cuatrimestre")
    9,10,11,12 -> println("corresponde al tercer cuatrimestre")
    else -> { println("No esta dentro de los meses del año")
    }
}
}

fun mesesRango(mes: Int) {
when(mes) {
    in 1..6 ->println("Primer semestres del año")
    in 7..12 ->println("Segundo  semestres del año") 
    !in 1..12 ->println("No corresponde a los meses que necesita") 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé si esta sea la respuesta que buscas pero puedes simplemente llamarlas una por una

```
fun llamadaAtodasLasFunciones(mes: Int) {
    meses2021(mes)
    apuntarMese(mes)
    mesesRango(mes)
}
```

Por cierto, si en todos los casos vas a a imprimir algo, te conviene sacar el `println` afuera del `when` para no tener que repetirlo:

```
fun meses2021(mesesCorrientes: Int) = println(
    when (mesesCorrientes) {
        1 -> "Enero"
        2 -> "Febrero"
        3 -> "Marzo"
        4 -> "Abril"
        5 -> "Mayo"
        6 -> "Junio"
        7 -> "Julio"
        8 -> "Agosto"
        9 -> "Septiembre"
        10 -> "Octubre"
        11 -> "Noviembre"
        12 -> "Diciembre"
        else -> "No esta dentro de los meses del año"
    }
)

fun apuntarMese(apuntar: Int) = println(
    when (apuntar) {
        1, 2, 3, 4 -> "corresponde al primer cuatrimestre"
        5, 6, 7, 8 -> "corresponde al segundo cuatrimestre"
        9, 10, 11, 12 -> "corresponde al tercer cuatrimestre"
        else -> "No esta dentro de los meses del año"
    }
)

fun mesesRango(mes: Int) = println(
    when (mes) {
        in 1..6 -> "Primer semestres del año"
        in 7..12 -> "Segundo  semestres del año"
        else -> "No corresponde a los meses que necesita"
    }
)
```

Comment: y en el caso que deseara darle a una función como parámetros otra función?

Comment: eso se llama [higher-order function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#higher-order-functions). Crea otra pregunta si quieres saber como aplicarlo a un caso específico

Comment: ok muchas gracias has sido de gran utilidad